# On screen Keyboard and Physical keyboard are not the same

Tags: keyboard

The characters are not same as the physical keyboard present in the laptop.Below both of the pics of the ON screen keyboard and the physical keyboard is attached:

[image: Physical keyboard]

[image: On-Screen Keyboard]

As both in the pics you can see that some of the keys don't match the physical keyboard.Few characters problems I am mentioning:

shift+2 prints " instead of @

shift+3 prints £ instead of #

Laptop model- ASUS TUF
              MODEL NO.- FX504GD-E4021T
Below the pics of laptop specs and the OS specs is attached:

[image: Specs 1]

What would be the problem? Is it a hardware problem or any other issue?

Comment: The physical keyboard is ANSI [a US standard]  The on-screen keyboard is ISO [a 'rest of the world' standard] Shift 2 and 3 would indicate it is set to UK English, rather than US English. I can't provide an actual answer as I don't know where you change them on Win10.

Comment: Thanks for the info but can you tell me that why this kind of manipulation occured as it has been more than 2 days that my friend bought the laptop?

Comment: @xychronite, does _"why this kind of manipulation occured as it has been more than 2 days that my friend bought the laptop"_ imply that things were different 2 days ago? (If so, please add those details to your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows 10 search bar enter "Edit language and keyboard options" and open this setting window.

You'll see a Region & Language page. Ensure all the drop down lists are set to your preferred region/language then under the Preferred languages header you should see what your preferred display language is set to.

Click this and an options button should appear. Click on options and in the new window, under the keyboards header, click Add a keyboard and pick the correct layout to match your hardware keyboard. In this case it looks like you will want to select English - US which is what your physical keyboard layout is.

You can then remove the old, incorrect layout after this.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect the hardware keyboard? I assume the hardware keyboard actually works okay. So, I assume that without any changes, Shift+2 already gets one `@`, just like indicated on that hardware keyboard? If I understand the question correctly then it's just that the two are different, but when using then both yield the characters that they show. @xychronite, can you confirm?

Comment: I thought the OP was looking his OS to reflect what his keyboard layout is. They state 'shift+2 prints " instead of @' which I took as his physical keyboard prints " instead of @. The physical keyboard is English - US layout while Windows has a English - UK layout or International. Although I'll wait for the OP to confirm incase I misread.

Comment: @Arjan I have checked my friend's laptop and corrected  the problem just like ResoundingBoom suggested. Actually the physical keyboard is a ANSI layout keyboard and what I have assumed is, during the first boot when OS has to be set up so by mistake instead of the US language pack,he(my friend) might have chosen the UK language pack for which the problem appeared. Now the problem is solved and no it was not a hardware fault.

Answer (score 0):

"Edit language and keyboard options"> English (United States) > options> add a keyboard> US(QWERTY)